# Классовое пространство имен без self

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтаксис

Я уже довольно давно пишу на питоне и никогда не задумывался над этим вопросом. Можно ли в питоне использовать поля и методы класса не указывая явно пространство имен как это делается в большинстве других языков? Вот, что я имею в виду

```
class Example:
    def inner_method1(self):
        print("abacaba")

    def inner_method2(self):
        inner_method1()


example = Example()
example.inner_method2()
```

Очевидно, работать так не будет, обращение к полю объекта должно быть таким:

```
self.inner_method1()
```

Когда кода много, все эти **self**'ы режут глаза. Можно ли обойтись без них?

*Скорее всего я сам знаю ответ на этот вопрос, хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение, зачем так сделано*

Comment: если self режет глаза, используйте свои имена. например this или Scrzii - будет работать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нельзя. Так заложено архитектурой языка.

Думаю, это можно описать следующей фразой из дзена питона (увидеть можно через `import this`):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Явное указание на текущий объект `self` и обращение через него, считаю, помогают ориентироваться в том к какой переменной/функции будет обращение. Ведь, если нет `self`, `cls`, то это глобальный объект

В пример ниже будет понятно, что будет вызвано:

```
def foo():
    print('foo()')


class Example:
    def foo(self):
        print("self.foo()")

    def inner_method2(self):
        foo()
        self.foo()


example = Example()
example.inner_method2()
```

Результат:

```
foo()
self.foo()
```

Как видно из результата, интерпретатор вызвал глобальную функцию, вместо внутренней.

Это отличается от логики в других языках, в которых без `this` поиск будет сначала внутри класса, например:

- [java](/questions/tagged/java) (https://onlinegdb.com/B_N2BoqQy):

  ```java
  public class Main
  {
      static void foo() {
         System.out.println("Main.foo");
      }

      static void bar() {
          System.out.println("Main.bar");
      }

      static class InnerClass {
          InnerClass() {
              foo();
              this.foo();
              bar();
          }

          void foo() {
              System.out.println("InnerClass.foo");
          }   
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          new InnerClass();
      }
  }
  ```

  Результат:

  ```
  InnerClass.foo
  InnerClass.foo
  Main.bar
  ```
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) (https://onlinegdb.com/KE7kfoRv8):

  ```cs
  using System;


  class HelloWorld {
      static void foo() {
         Console.WriteLine("foo");
      }

      static void bar() {
         Console.WriteLine("bar");
      }

      class InnerClass {
          public InnerClass() {
              foo();
              this.foo();
              bar();
          }

          void foo() {
              Console.WriteLine("InnerClass.foo");
          }
      }

      static void Main() {
          new InnerClass();
      }
  }
  ```

  Результат:

  ```
  InnerClass.foo
  InnerClass.foo
  Main.bar
  ```
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (https://onlinegdb.com/0fns14VmB):

  ```cpp
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;


  void foo() {
     cout << "foo" << endl;
  }

  void bar() {
     cout << "bar" << endl;
  }

  class HelloWorld {
  public:
      HelloWorld() {
          foo();
          this->foo();
          bar();
      }

      void foo() {
         cout << "HelloWorld.foo" << endl;
      }
  };


  int main()
  {
      HelloWorld obj;

      return 0;
  }
  ```

  Результат:

  ```
  HelloWorld.foo
  HelloWorld.foo
  bar
  ```

---

**PS.**

> Когда кода много, все эти self'ы режут глаза

Не знаю... у меня наличие `self` не вызывало проблем :) Наоборот, это дает понимание какие переменные/функции относятся к текущему объекту, а какие внешние

**PPS.**

Вместо `self` можно использовать другое, в данном случае это просто аргумент методов объекта, но так не рекомендуется делать.

В целях образования, пример:

```
class Example:
    abc = 123

    def foo(this):
        print(this.abc)

    def inner_method2(_):
        _.foo()


example = Example()
example.inner_method2()
```

Comment: я понимаю, что мой коммент просто перекопировали... но с++ код зачем сюда...

Comment: @KoVadim, вообще, я про него первым вспомнил - он ближе к примеру ЯП, чем первые 2, т.к. позволяет объявить функции вне классов :) Комментарий у вас хороший :)